# Check instance metrics

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

is there any way to check if instance got any metrics using OCI Python SDK?
Will be `list_metrics` from `oci.monitoring.MonitoringClient` good method to check if there is some metrics collected for instance?